# Python 3.4.1 input

Tags: python-3.4

When I run this script, it asks for the input. But then, it ends on the pause and doesn't prints anything. Some solution? 
PS:This is Python 3.4.1

```
variable = input('What do you want to be?: ')
    if variable is 'a unicorn' :
        print ('You are now a unicorn!')
    elif variable is 'a pig' :
        print ('You are now a pig!')
    pause = input #This is here just to pause the script
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to know the difference between `is` and  `==`

- `==` is for **value equality**. Use it when you would like to know if two objects have the same value.
- `is` is for **reference equality**. Use it when you would like to know if two references refer to the same object.

```
>>> variable = 'a unicorn'
>>> variable is 'a unicorn'
False
>>> variable == 'a unicorn'
True
```

just replace `is` with `==`

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to programming and I'm suprised i didn't find this anywhere else.